# Reorder matrix in Matlab by putting at the end rows with NaN

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix in Matlab of dimension `mx2`. Some rows of the matrix can contain a `NaN` in the first OR (not and) in the second column. I want to reorder the rows of the matrix by putting the rows with `NaN` at the end. Moreover,  I want to list firstly the rows with a `NaN` in the second column and then  the rows with a `NaN` in the first column.

For example

```
A=[NaN   11;
    10    NaN;
    5     8;
    2     0;
    NaN   3;
    9     NaN;
    1000  0];

A_new= [5 8; 
        2 0; 
        1000 0; 
        10 NaN; 
        9 NaN; 
        NaN 11; 
        NaN 3];
```

Could you help me to write this piece of code? I have tried with `sort` first and then reorder

```
[ii ii] = sort(sum(isnan(A),2))
out = A(ii,:)
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isnan` + `sortrows`:

```
n = isnan(A);              % a binary matrix representing position of nan
[~,idx]= sortrows(n);      % get indexes for sorted elements
A_new = A(idx,:);          % reorder the matrix based on idx

A_new =
      5      8
      2      0
   1000      0
     10    NaN
      9    NaN
    NaN     11
    NaN      3
```